# Fetching Data from API Error , Unexpected end of JSON input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, fetch-api

After creating my API, I enabled CORS Following this TUTO :https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1150023/Enable-Cross-origin-Resource-Sharing-CORS-in-ASP-N

I want to fetch Data from my API using REACT JS, I want to show a list of "Experiences" so I use this URL : 'http://localhost:51492/api/experience/'

This is my code to fetch Data from API:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const API = 'http://localhost:51492/api/experience/';
const DEFAULT_QUERY = 'redux';

class LoadMoreList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      hits: [],
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch(API + DEFAULT_QUERY)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => this.setState({ hits: data.hits }));
  }

  render() {
    const { hits } = this.state;

    return (
      <ul>
        {hits.map(hit =>
          <li key={hit.id}>
            <a href={hit.url}>{hit.titre}</a>
          </li>
        )}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}

 

LoadMoreList.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

export default withStyles()(LoadMoreList);
```

but I got:

> Unhandled Rejection (SyntaxError): Unexpected end of JSON input
> and in devTools i got : Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input

I also configured the file  aplicationhost.config and I added this:

```
<httpProtocol>
 <customHeaders>
  <clear />
   <add name="X-Powered-By" value="ASP.NET" />
   <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
   <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
   <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />

 </customHeaders>
    <redirectHeaders>
                <clear />
            </redirectHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

Does my configuration miss something?

---

UPDATE:
JSON result is :

[image]

Comment: try to change to this                .then(data => this.setState({ hits: data }));

Comment: What error are you getting if you look at the error message of the request in the Network tab of your developer tools?

Comment: Can you post the `shape/schema` or JSON returned?

Comment: @Serdar i got the same error : Unhandled Rejection (SyntaxError): Unexpected end of JSON input
thank u

Comment: @Tholle i got this : Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 ()
2randomuser.me/api/?results=5&inc=name,gender,email,nat&noinfo:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 503 ()
:1 Failed to load https://randomuser.me/api/?results=5&inc=name,gender,email,nat&noinfo: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.
Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input

Comment: i don't understand from where he got this fake api https://randomuser.me/api/?results=5&inc=name,gender,email,nat&noinfo
when i followed a tuto , it was using this api , but i replaced it with mine
THANK U

Comment: @Sung Kim i updated  my question , i added a capture of the Json result
thank u

Comment: i've removed : const DEFAULT_QUERY = 'redux';

but this time i got this error : TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined